# Accessing Virtual Hosts Across a Local Network

Tags: apache, vhosts

I've 2 machine on my local network. On my first machine A, i've creat a vhost mysite.lan and i want access to this vhost with my machine B.

If i don't edit my host file, i do not access.

Do you know if i can access on my vhost without edit my host file ?

My vhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName wordpress.lan
     ServerAlias www.wordpress.lan
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.wordpress.lan/webroot/
     ErrorLog /var/www/html/www.wordpress.lan/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/html/www.wordpress.lan/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something on your network to read these requests and forward them to the correct address - in the absence of anything else an entry in the hosts file will do this.

Your router contains DNS servers, either entered manually or populated by your internet service provider. By default, these servers provide lookup information for DNS queries. You can run a DNS server locally, but it's a lot of work to achieve what you're looking for.

See this link for info on doing this on Linux (I'm not sure what OS you're on, but I assume it's either Mac or Linux based on format of your vhost entry):

https://superuser.com/questions/45789/running-dns-locally-for-home-network